# Is there any conflict between jquery-steps and cropit?

Tags: jquery, laravel-4, jquery-steps

I am using jquery-step in a form. In the first step, the user image is loaded by cropit-js. The problem is that the cropit modal can't be shown when the jquery-step script is loaded.

```
 {{ HTML::script('js/vendor/jquery.steps/jquery.steps.min.js');}}
 {{ HTML::script('js/vendor/cropit/jquery.cropit.min.js');}}
```

The version of cropit is 0.4.1
The version of jquery-steps is 1.1.0

Any ideas about this issue?

I am running this on Laravel 4.2

Comment: Does jQuery.js already exist in page when both of these load? What errors are thrown?

Comment: Yes, jquery.js does (v 2.1.4). No errors are thrown..

Comment: When I comment the function `form.children(".wizard").steps({...})`  the cropit modal backs to work. –

Comment: @cosmopod Did you resolve this later?